# Custom function for onPush change detection in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, angular2-changedetection

```
{ id:123, version 1, ...}
```

I am writing an Angular 2 component that uses the onPush change detection strategy.  I'd like to know if there is a way to use custom logic with onPush when determining if an object has changed.  My understanding is that onPush checks the object reference an so only updates when a new instance of an object is sent.

My app tracks its own versioning for objects which means that every object has an id and version number.  I periodically refresh data from the server which means that a new object is instantiated even though the data has not actually changed.  This means there are cases with the default onPush that would see a new instantiated object and think it has to update.  In actuality the id and version number are the same so even though the the object reference has changed I can skip updating the component.

I'd like to be able to provide a custom function to onPush that essentially  uses a function like this to do change checking.

```
(obj1, obj2) => obj1.id === obj2.id && obj1.version === obj2.version
```

Is it possible to customize the onPush logic, or is there another way to achieve this so that I don't need to unnecessarily update the component when the object reference changes but the data does not.

Comment: there is no way to create costum `changeDetectionStrategy`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that it's possible to create a custom `changeDetectionStrategy` . But if you do track the change on your objects by yourself you can do something (probably) even more optimized.

You can inject the `ChangeDetectorRef` and tell Angular that your component shouldn't be watched anymore (which is pretty cool and powerful !).

```
constructor(private _cd: ChangeDetectorRef)

ngOnInit() {
  this._cd.detach();
}

ngOnChanges() {
  // check if your objects have changed here
  // if they've changed, tells Angular to check
  // the bindings manually
  this._cd.detectChanges();
}
```

Comment: So checking the version and id would go right before the .detectChanges() and if they match you don't call it?

Comment: Yep ! Call `detectChanges` if you consider that your data have changed